# ImportError at /admin: No module named defaults

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am upgrading my site from django 1.4 to django 1.6, and it kept came out with this error: ImportError at /admin:  No module named defaults. Everywhere else say you should do:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
# should be
from django.conf.urls import *
```

But I didn't find "from django.conf.urls.defaults import *" from anywhere in my code. The debugger indicates that the exception location is:

```
Exception Location: /home/.../webapps/healthtweets_dev/lib/python2.7/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 40
```

And it highlighted the admin.autodiscover() in the traceback:

```
/home/.../webapps/healthtweets_dev/healthtweets/code/health_tweets/urls.py in <module>

admin.autodiscover()
```

I am sure that I have installed python 1.6.2 and I can't find where the default module was imported in my code. Does anyone have some ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've removed all instances of `defaults`, then it's one of 2 problems.

1: Your compiled python files are still referencing old data. Sometimes happens. Remove all pyc files in your project to force recompilation. `find . -name "*.pyc" | xargs rm`

2: An app in `INSTALLED_APPS` is still using `<1.6` syntax to set up patterns. Search your site-packages directory for this pattern or remove third party apps from INSTALLED_APPS until you find it.

Comment: I removed an app from INSTALLED_APPS and it works. Thank you!

Comment: NP! Glad you found it. What was it?

Comment: It's "constance", I was using constance 0.4, and it's 0.6 now.