# how to recompile django project

Tags: python, django, excel

I am trying to run a program as given on
http://www.thepythontree.in/source-code-8-django-app-to-extract-excel-sheet-data-into-db/ .
I have made a few changes like username & password.

On compiling it gives an error "No module named defaults". I referred to a stackoverflow post 
[ImportError at /admin: No module named defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110481/importerror-at-admin-no-module-named-defaults)
it asks to recompile. how do i recompile this. or is there any problem with the code.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manually compile Python scripts, they are compiled at runtime by the Python interpreter.

The error you are seeing is saying that it can't find a module called "defaults". In Python, a module is either a Python file or a directory containing Python files.

Somewhere, you will have a Python script with a line like "import defaults", or "from defaults import *". You need to make sure that "defaults" can be imported by that script.

**Make sure you have a file called "defaults.py"**

I had a look at the code linked to on the page you've linked from, I couldn't see any imports for "defaults".

For further diagnosis, you need to provide the full error message you are getting, and the file and directory structure of your project.

Comment: Thanks, The problem is now resolved. somehow in urls.py we did not remove the ".defaults" from import statement.